# Spring Boot And Thymeleaf remain on the same page on post request is made

Tags: spring, spring-boot, html-table, model, thymeleaf

I've created an web app that searches for online car ads and populates the page with a few tables after a post request.It looks like this:

[image]

After Search:

[image]

Every table element has a save button which should save those values to the database but my problem is that the page gets refreshed after submitting a post request. How can I do this without refreshing the page?

Table:

```
  <form th:action="@{/saveAd}" method="POST">
    <table class="table table-sm table-hover">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>Imagine</th>
            <th>Titlu Anunt</th>
            <!-- <th style="width: 16.66%">Link</th> -->
            <th>Pret</th>
            <th>Oras</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody id="myTable">
       <th:block th:each="element : ${lista}">
        <trth:onclick="'javascript:rowClicked(\'' + ${element.url} + '\');'">
          <td><img th:src="@{${element.img}}" class="size" /></td>
          <td th:text="${element.title}"></td>
          <td th:text="${element.pret}"></td>
          <td th:text="${element.oras}"></td>
          <td><input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit"value="Save"></td>
          </tr>
      </th:block>
    </tbody>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/saveAd", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveAd(@ModelAttribute("adValue") AdValue adValue) {
    System.out.println(adValue.getImg());
    System.out.println(adValue.getLink());
    System.out.println(adValue.getOras());
    System.out.println(adValue.getPret());
    System.out.println(adValue.getTitle());
    return "home";
}
```

And also, how could I bind the list to a model object after pressing the save button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you may like this project. It is similar with what you need : 
https://github.com/adinafometescu/tutorials/tree/master/spring-elasticsearch

You can use .bootstrapTable(). It a very method to update dynamically your table.

```
<table id="car-table" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="id">Id</th>
        <th data-field="title">Title</th>
        <th data-field="price">Price</th>
        <th data-field="city">City</th>
        <th data-width="10" data-formatter="saveButtonFormatter"/>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

The beauty is that it will map the data-field to a java object.
js stuff:

```
function saveButtonFormatter(value, row, index){
    var adId = row.id;
    return "<button class=\"btn btn-danger \" data-title=\"Save\" 
    data-toggle=\"modal\" onclick=\"saveAd(\'"+adId+"\')\" 
    </button>"
}
```

The function saveAd(adId) will call the rest endpoint and will update the bootstrap table on success.

I see that in your thymeleaf you don't have inputs. I suggest to not post your entire object if you don't need user input, just the id.

```
// anotate the controller class with @RestController

@Autowired
AdService adService;

@PostMapping(path = "/ad/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> saveAd(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    adService.saveAd(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
}
```

P.S : don't write code in Romanian :D